# pandas: plot histogram with time on x axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, histogram

I have a Dataframe `df` like that:

```
Datetime                 Dollar

2009-08-01 00:00:00        87

2009-08-01 00:15:00        32 

2009-08-01 00:30:00        19 

2009-08-01 00:45:00       128
```

If I try `df.hist()`, I only get the values (ascending) on the `x` axis and the specific quantity on the `y` axis. But I need the timestamp on the `x` axis for analyzing the changes in value over the time.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `df.plot()` would be suitable here. You could write:

```
df.plot('Datetime', 'Dollar', kind='bar', rot=45)
```

which gives:

[image]

To detail the arguments used in `plot` above: 'Datetime' and 'Dollar' indicate the columns to use for the x-axis and y-axis values respectively; the `kind` keyword argument is used to specify a bar chart; the `rot` keyword argument simply rotates the x-axis labels for readability.

Comment: Okay. Thanks!!! Just of interest: What should I do, if the Datetime column has no label 'Datetime'. If there are just timestamps?!

Comment: @EP1986 No problem. By default, columns are named with numbers `0`, `1`, and so on. In this case, `df.plot(0, 1, kind='bar', rot=45)` would produce the plot here.

Comment: Now I am getting a Memory Error and it runs more than seven minutes. (the first "wrong" hist plot needs around one minute) Any idea, what I can do?

Comment: If you have a huge DataFrame, plotting bar graphs can be quite memory-intensive. It might be work trying to plot smaller ranges of values first.